# Capistrano Bundler error on deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler

I am trying to use capistrano to deploy and bundle my rails application.
When I run cap deploy - or more specifically

```
bundle exec cap staging bundler:install --trace
```

I seem to have a perpetual error with the following stack trace.

```
** Invoke staging (first_time)
** Execute staging
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke bundler:map_bins (first_time)
** Execute bundler:map_bins
** Invoke bundler:install (first_time)
** Execute bundler:install
DEBUG [bd567504] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/www/TMC/current; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/TMC/current'" 1>&2; false; fi on 162.243.225.14
DEBUG [bd567504] Command: if test ! -d /var/www/TMC/current; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/TMC/current'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [bd567504] Finished in 1.443 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [2058712b] Running /usr/bin/env bundle install --binstubs /var/www/TMC/shared/bin --path /var/www/TMC/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet on 162.243.225.14
DEBUG [2058712b] Command: cd /var/www/TMC/current && /usr/bin/env bundle install --binstubs /var/www/TMC/shared/bin --path /var/www/TMC/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
DEBUG [2058712b]    /usr/bin/env: bundle: No such file or directory
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 127
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: /usr/bin/env: bundle: No such file or directory
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.4.0/lib/sshkit/command.rb:98:in `exit_status='
```

I used chef to provision the machine and setup RBENV etc so i am not using capistrano/rbenv.
The relevant section of my gemfile reads:

```
group :development do
      gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.0.0'
      gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1.2'
end
```

I had to login and manually create the current directory in the /var/www/TMC/current path.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you have gem Bundler installed on the server for you current rvm?
It looks like bundle is not installed on your server. Try installing bundler first:

```
sudo apt-get install bundler
```

Comment: Shouldn't Bundler be installed with RubyGems? This package definitely exists in the apt repositories but it didn't solve the issue at all.